# Firebase Messaging service worker send notification

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

In the Firebase Messaging docs there is an example on how you can send a notification to the browser via the registered serviceworker in the javscript file:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

But sadly there is no example how I can do the same for the foreground:

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

this.afMessaging.messages
        .subscribe((message) => { 
            const title = 'TEST';
            const options = {
              body: message["data"].text,
              icon: 'assets/icon.png',
              badge: 'assets/badge.png',
              actions: [
                { 
                  action: 'archive',
                  title: 'archive'
                }
              ]
            };
            
            //let notification = new Notification(title, options);
            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => reg.showNotification(title, options));
```

I used before the `new Notification` but this does not support actions.
So I need to use the showNotification from the serviceworker, but how can I access it from the typescript code.
With the current implementation I get always the error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined
```

Comment: You can use ``firebase.messaging().onMessage()`` function which returns a promise with the payload of notification. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive)

Comment: Thanks I get the message from firebase.messaging, but I want to show a desktop notification afterwards. The same as self.registration.showNotification

Comment: What do you mean by desktop notification. Either you receive notification in browser or inside the app.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please also help me. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67996382/14552734)

Comment: Let me explain: My Android app sends a message/text to the browser and the browser should show this message as desktop notification --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification